# TypeError: Undefined is not a function - Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, typeerror

So I'm currently learning `Sails.js` through following some tutorials and I have encountered this problem many times now.

I tried searching for the solutions but none of them seemed to work.

```
module.exports = {
signup: function(req, res) {
    var username = req.param("username");
    var password = req.param("password");

    Users.findByUsername(username).done(function(err, usr){
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, { error: "DB Error" });
        } else if (usr) {
            res.send(400, {error: "Username already Taken"});
        } else {
            var hasher = require("password-hash");
            password = hasher.generate(password);

            Users.create({username: username, password: password}).done(function(error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    res.send(500, {error: "DB Error"});
                } else {
                    req.session.user = user;
                    res.send(user);
                }
            });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The problems seems to be on this line, it says that:

> undefined is not a function.

```
Users.findByUsername(username).done(function(err, usr)
```

It seems to me that the problem is on the `.done` because when I try to make it like this:

```
Users.findByUsername(username, function(err, usr)
```

it works.

This is my `Users.js` under model

```
module.exports = {
attributes: {
    username: 'STRING',
    password: 'STRING'
 }
};
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Also in chrome console the status code is :

> 500 Internal Server Error

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

May be you are following some tutorial which is written for previous version of SailsJS. In previous version there was a function named `done`, which is replaced by `exec` in newer versions. Try replacing `done` with `exec`. Then the code will be like,

```
module.exports = {
signup: function(req, res) {
    var username = req.param("username");
    var password = req.param("password");

    Users.findByUsername(username).exec(function(err, usr){
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, { error: "DB Error" });
        } else if (usr) {
            res.send(400, {error: "Username already Taken"});
        } else {
            var hasher = require("password-hash");
            password = hasher.generate(password);

            Users.create({username: username, password: password}).done(function(error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    res.send(500, {error: "DB Error"});
                } else {
                    req.session.user = user;
                    res.send(user);
                }
            });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you sir! :) I guess I'd have to check the versions of sails.js thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem caused by the fact that the `.done()` function is now deprecated in `sails.js` and it's probably removed but you can replace it with `.exec()`function.

That's why the Exception `TypeError: Undefined is not a function` is raised here, because this function does no longer exists and belongs to old versions of `sails.js` and it's now Deprecated.

You can find more abiout it in **[this discussion here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1607)**.

So your code should be:

```
Users.findByUsername(username).exec(function(err, usr){
```